# how to algorithmically prove the sup and inf of a set

Tags: real-analysis

I know how to find the sup or inf of a set but always stuck as to what i am aiming for. 
is there a process I can use to prove the inf or sup of a set?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no single algorithm.

First of all if you can find a maximum for the set then that's the supremum. For example the set $[0,1]$ has the maximum $1$ since both $1$ is in the set and no element is larger than $1$.

Otherwise one normally starts with an educated guess. Let's say that your set is $(0,1)$ then you'll have a good reason to assume that $1$ is the supremum. Now the first step is to prove that $1$ is an upper bound which is trivial since every number in $(0,1)$ is actually less than $1$. Next step is to prove that it's the lowest and that's done by simply picking any number lower than $1$ and find a number in $(0,1)$ that's larger (for example $\max (1, 1+x)/2 > x$ if $x<1$.

Another more advanced approach is to use an increasing sequence in the set, that sequence would have a limit not larger than the supremum of the set. Also a decreasing sequence of upper bounds has a limit not less than the supremum. If the limit of two such sequences coincide they must be the supremum. For example if we take the sequence $a_n = 1-2^{-n}\in(0,1)$, we see that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 1$ and therefore $\sup (0,1)\ge 1$ (and since $1$ is an upper bound it we have $\sup(0,1)\le 1$ and therefore $\sup (0,1)=1$).

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how your set is defined.  For a set with a maximimum or minimum value,  you simply pick out the largest or smallest value.  However,  for infinite sets, with no maximum or minimum value, you want to find the complement of your set,  partition it to upper and lower bounds of your set and find the min and max respectively.   i.e. let's say your set is $(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R} $,  it's complement is $(-\infty, 0] \cup [1, \infty) $ of which the upper bounds of your set are $[1, \infty) $ the min of which is $1$. Thus $1$ is your sup.  A similar process yields $0$ as your inf.

If your set contains no maximum (minimum value) and the set of all upper bounds (lower bounds) contains no minimum (maximum) then the sup (inf) does not exist.

Comment: It also worth noting,  that in many cases this argument is apparent and not necessary to explain. However for more complicated sets, the same reasoning should work.

Comment: im my lectures we are often expected to use Archimedes property that 0<1/n<x where does that come into it

Comment: First of all the upper partition may be open which means that it will have no minimum. Take for example if the set is $[0,1]$. Second it's not always that trivial to construct the complement either - take for example the set $\{\sin n\}$.

Comment: But $\sup(-\infty,0]$ do exists, it's $0$.

Comment: Ahh! of course it does, it just doesn't contain its sup. Scratch that.